# Why using merge function in R creates duplicates?

Tags: r, merge

I am running merge function in R:

```
Example:

DF <- merge(DF1, DF2, by = c("Date", "Time"), all.x= TRUE)
```

However, When I run the code, I get duplicated rows!
How can I get unique rows from the function? and why I am getting these duplicated rows?

Comment: it is because you have dupes for the 'Date', 'Time' in the dataset

Comment: @akrun,I did not understand what does that mean? and how can I clean that?

Comment: It means that `DF1 <- data.frame(col1 = rep(1:3, each = 2)); DF2 <- data.frame(col1 = c(1, 1:3), col2 = runif(4)); merge(DF1, DF2, all.x = TRUE)` in this example there are dupes for col1 in both datasets and merging by that column results in the confusion

Comment: If you want `merge()` to return unique rows on 'Date' and 'Time', then you have to ensure that both DF1 and DF2 have unique rows in those two variables. Perhaps you need to explain what information those two data frames contain and why you want to merge them.

Comment: Does `DF <- merge(unique(DF1), unique(DF2), by = c("Date", "Time"), all.x= TRUE)` solve the problem ?

Comment: @RonakShah, thanks! that works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can get only the `unique` rows of `DF1` and `DF2` and then `merge`.

```
DF <- merge(unique(DF1), unique(DF2), by = c("Date", "Time"), all.x= TRUE)
```